# Python pyip udp module object has no attribute 'Packet'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed the pyip package via pip using the following line

```
 sudo pip install pyip
```

The package appeared to install successfully, however, when I try to use the udp module to create a packet using the following code, it fails...

```
udp_probe = udp.Packet()
```

I can see the udp module in the [PyIP Package Details](http://pydoc.net/pyip/0.7/udp/) with the class `Packet`

I am new to python, can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message? Did you `import udp; udp.Packet()`?

Comment: module object has no attribute 'Packet'